Add an ArrayList into a Queue (LinkedList)
As I know, we can make create a Queue using syntax along the lines of Queue<Integer> = new LinkedList<>().
But when I try to add the ArrayList<Integer> element into the Queue<Integer> with the .add() method, it doesn't work.
I was considering two solutions to fix this issue:

Use Queue<ArrayList<Integer>> instead of Queue<Integer>
Use Queue<Integer> and add the ArrayList by Queue.addAll()

Which of these should I use?

Java is strongly typed, so Integer and ArrayList<Integer> are not the same thing. Just make up your mind what you really want the type to be. The two solutions are fine, but give different results. Up to you to decide. Note that in the second solution you are not adding the ArrayList, you're adding the values from the ArrayList.

Are you adding ArrayList instance or it's elements? Can you show how you are doing .add()

"I want to cook dinner, and I read some people like strawberries, while some people have beef in their recipe, which is the best answer?" without telling us whether you are making a dessert or a stew. Both are good, but have completely different uses. Only you know what you want to have as elements in your queue, lists of integers or individual integers.

Your two implementations do very different things.
Option 1 is for when you want to create a Queue of ArrayLists. In this case, each item in the queue would be a complete list, and adding a new item with .add would append one whole list to the queue. A Queue<ArrayList<Integer>> would give you a 2D structure like this:
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

Option 2 is for when you want to create a Queue of Integers. In this case, each item in the queue would be an individual number, and "adding" a list with .addAll would append each item in the list to the queue sequentially. This method would give you a 1D structure like this:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Which one is "better" depends on your use case - it's beyond the scope of this site to give you a specific recommendation given the limited information you've provided.

QueueInteger and Queue.addAll() is more common and likely the better approach because it keeps the queue's purpose clear and focused on handling integers.

Even if you are storing e.g. a list of lottery combinations?... It is trivially obvious that lists of integers are more common than lists of lists of integers (because each non-empty list of lists of integers has lists of integers); but whether they are better or not is impossible to answer without considering the purpose, which is notably missing from the OP question.

yes, because what's more clear a purpose than "handling integers"? We all know what those int handlers do in their spare time too. The deviants.  You can't know its purpose and no functional human is confused by its kind. .
